# Used my laptop to install on usb. Now cant boot the hdd install. urgent

Tags: grub2

Im writing this from my phone because i messed up big time and need to fix it asap.
I used my ubuntu laptop to make installed ubuntu on a usb stick (booted from live usb to make it)
I choose the usb for both the install and boot partition, yet it still messed my hdd boot partition (i guess) and now it jues goes into grub> terminal black screen.
 How do i tell it to use the right partition again?
Whole hdd was encrypted when it was installed.

If i dont fix that asap im in serious trouble. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you boot into grub, do you see the bash command line or a plain black screen?

Comment: 1) Is the original data on the laptop important? 2) Is there another computer you have access to?

Comment: I see the command line and can write commands in grub. Data is important. I have old windows laptop nearby if really needed.

Comment: First, try to boot into some partition manager or setup module to see if you're data is safe.

Comment: I ran gparted from the live usb. Partition is there but encrypted. I just need to make it boot it.

Comment: Try running `ls` from Grub 2 and note down the partitions on a paper.

Comment: Now even grub terminal wont start but just blank black screen. Wtf?

Comment: Continously press `Shift` while booting and then press `C` in the grub menu for a command line.